# Update Tracker name and resend Google analytics for android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am integrating google Analytics sdk in my app. I need to update screen name on basis of content shown on the app.
Currently I am using

```
com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker t = AnalyticsApplication.getTracker(this, TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName(post.getTitle());
    t.setTitle(post.getTitle());
    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

The problem is, when this activity is closed via back button and then reopened, instead of saving new posts.getTitle, it is still using previous one.

Is there any way to send new screen name?

Comment: why not use something like this : tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Login",
      "User was logged in (a)", "", 0l).build());

Comment: I tried that too just now. The problem is, when the same activity reloads, GA is unable to keep track of that, Given that screen name is dynamic, I can see that GA is still stucked at previous activity launch or ignoring my dynamic nomenclature.

Comment: You mean to say that post.getTitle() (or new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder()) not changed ?

Comment: Actually post.getTitle changed. but there was no new hit to GA. It still shows previous post.getTitle..